# Necesito verificar los caracteres de una cadena

Tags: java, string, regex, email

Necesito un programa que al ingresar un correo electrónico verifique:
1. Si el nombre del correo contiene caracteres especiales (solo permite alfanuméricos)
2. Si contiene arroba.
3. Si el nombre del dominio es correcto (Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook, Hotmail).

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```java
String correo;
        Boolean verif,verif2;
        System.out.println("\n Ingrese un correo de formato nombre@dominio.com : \n");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        correo=input.next();
        int ind=correo.indexOf("@");
        for (int cont=0; cont<ind ; cont++) {
            char c=correo.charAt(cont);
            if (c=='[^A-Za-z0-9]') {
                verif=false;
            }
        String dominio=correo.substring(ind,correo.length());
        if (dominio=="@gmail.com" or "@hotmail.com" or "@outlook.com" or "@yahoo.com") {
            verif2=true;
        }
        if (verif==true && verif2==true) {
            System.out.println("Ha Ingresado un correo valido.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Ha ingresado un correo invalido.")
        }
```

Lo que no sé es como verificar que cada caracter sea alfanumérico recorriendo el string hasta el @.

Comment: Hay una libraria externa usando por muchos: [Apache Commons EmailValidator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator). La documentacion [aqui](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html). Hay metodo para verificar si un email address es valido o no, pero no hay metodo para probar si los emails son de ciertos domains. Esto tiene que hacerlo con su propio codigo.

Comment: No entiendo, ya lo tienes resuelto. Si `verif` es `true` es porque todos los caracteres son alfanuméricos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo he optado por validarlo mediante una expresión regular, ya que resulta más sencillo y toma en cuenta todos los posibles casos para ello. Espero y te sirva.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class STOF2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            STOF2 s = new STOF2();
            String email = "josuerojasvega@gmail.com";
            System.out.println(s.validarCorreo(email));

        }

        public boolean validarCorreo(String correo) {
             Pattern patron = Pattern
                        .compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
             Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(correo);
             return matcher.find();
        }
}
```

Comment: Sí, vi ese método en varias páginas. El inconveniente inicial es que no sé bien cómo funciona, pero de todas formas mi profesor quiere que haga la función básica, tratando de evitar las librerías y hacerlo de más bajo nivel posible. ¿Existe una forma para verificar caracter por caracter si es alfanumérico o no?

Comment: Si claro, puedes recorrer un String caracter por caracter con charAt() y puedes usar isDigit(caracter) para que con un booleano este te diga true en caso de ser un numero o false sino

Comment: Gracias, ¿Y para alfabético?

Comment: Podrias usar que !isDigit  y buscar una funcion para saber si es un signo de puntuacion y tambien negarlo para que por descarte solo quede si son letras